# Assigning variables on items on a list and use the values in printing desired output

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I trying to create a script that will output a configuration file for Aruba wireless access points SSID.

I would like to have a one liner input for the access points separated by comma and each input will be read and assigned a unique variable which will then be used/called in the config script.

The tricky part here is the number of access points is not fixed as it will depend on the user request. I would like to make the script in such a way that it can accommodate any given input like this:

```
items = input("Enter the list of devices here: \n") ## 
AP01,AP05,AP06,AP10,AP15 ## The list number is unknown as it varies depending on the need
```

And output something like this:

```
ap1 = items[0]
ap2 = items[1]
ap3 = items[2]
.
.
.
.
apn = items[n]

apconf1 = "ap-name" + " " + ap1\n + "vap-profile Test101_vprof"
apconf1 = "ap-name" + " " + ap2\n + "vap-profile Test101_vprof"
apconf1 = "ap-name" + " " + ap3\n + "vap-profile Test101_vprof"
.
.
.
.
apconfn = "ap-name" + " " + apn\n + "vap-profile Test101_vprof"
```

And then print something like this:

```
print(apconf1)
print(apconf2)
print(apconf3)
.
.
.
.
print(apconfn)
```

The desired output is:

```
ap-name AP01
vap-profile Test101_vprof
ap-name AP05
vap-profile Test101_vprof
ap-name AP06
vap-profile Test101_vprof
.
.
.
.
ap-name APn
vap-profile Test101_vprof
```

Any inputs will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `items.split(',')` is your fried, and the accepted answer :-)

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace for pointing me to the previous solution. Been searching for weeks for this. I guess I'm not using the correct search string :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you get that input to a list your problems can be sorted out

```
itemlist=[i for i in itemtext.split(',')]
```

Comment: Hey, why need to loop, and do nothing with it?, just `itemtext.split(',')` is enough.

Comment: I think he needs to get in printed individually so if we get that to a list it's easier to make it more dynamic.

Comment: hi guys, appreciate everyone's help on this. The solution pointed out by DeepSpace worked for me :)

Comment: @AmilaMGunawardana `itemtext.split(',')==[i for i in itemtext.split(',')]` is the thing that will blow your mind, haha.